Need to replace pull down stair spreader hinge
I am looking for the spreader hinges for an attic pull down stair that was installed in the mid to late 1990s. There is no brand name on the stairs.
I have googled , searching sites, but most of them say manufactured AFTER 2010.
The couple I have found that fit older stairs , have a review stating it's made of cheap metal.
The dimensions on the newer replacement part are slightly off from my model.
Any suggestions ?
Could the newer parts fit ?
Where can I look for the right part ?

There are lots of hinge sets out there but many of them " only for ladders after 2010" Mine have been in place since the late 1990s.

I wonder if there was some code change in 2010.

If you have the typical one that is like an extension ladder with a couple of spring-loaded lever arms, you can buy an "attic ladder hinge arms" set that includes both arms in entirety, or a kit that also includes new springs.     These cost $30 to $80 so IMO you're better off replacing the arms completely than trying to find parts for something with no markings that has already broken once and will probably cost about the same.

That is what I'm asking about. But how do I know if I'm getting a set that will work with my ladder. Some say not for ladders before 2010

Measure yours and compare with the measurements in the listings.
